# How to use request-promise in a front-end javascript

Tags: javascript

I m trying to use request-promise in a front end javascript file.
I tried to use the cdnjs link which is

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/request-promise/4.2.5/rp.js" integrity="sha256-KsyWbeTLHIsXgXF6kzbMgmRFaDnEIquh9rL53NK+aBA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

When I use this.I get a error in my developer console.

[image: error in developer console.]

It says

```
Uncaught Refrence error:require is not defined
```

I am new to javascript can any one please help me out on how I can use request-promise on a front-end javascript file.Any help is appreciated.THANK YOU

Comment: you must to calling `require` in wrong way, can you share relevant index.js section

Comment: index.js is from the request-promise index.js file.I do not have access.I have linked request-promise through cdn

Comment: Browsers doesn't have `require`. Instead, you'll have to use a module bundler, like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request-promise` was not designed for and does not support browser javascript (see [this github issue](https://github.com/request/request-promise/issues/60)). You can use [`superagent`](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) or just use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Comment: i guess i can use Fetch API or axios or jQuery's AJAX  right?

Answer (score 0):

If you called by `script`, you don't need to use `require` for the file, browser will handle for you. You can open the devtool and go to the network tab, find the XHR and see whether you things has been fetched.

Besides, `require` can only be used in node environment. It belongs to `CommonJS` if you want to find out more information. It is not a standard Javascript API. Therefore, it is undefined in browser.